# How to make custom rounded corners in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to construct a rounded corner with Illustrator. I know that there's a style/effect rounded corner, but I need to have 2-3 borders around the rectangle, all rounded, so, it's not that easy.

Take a look: http://ioj.com/v/99ngb

It looks horrible. Are there easier ways to accomplish this... and is there a way to define the position for an anchor (I am talking about those two subanchors that appear when u want smooth curves)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overlay a copy of the shape over the one what forms your base, then use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and drag one of the corner transform boxes to shrink the top shape like so:

[image]

1. Create shape 1
2. Duplicate shape 1 and overlay the duplicate (shape 2) over shape 1
3. Shrink the overlaying shape 2 by using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + drag transform box

Do the above as much as you need borders.

Comment: Oh, of course. Thank you so much, you even take the time to make the pictures, I appreciate your efforts!

Comment: @tower you are very welcome! =) It's all part of the service! ;)